How can I mitigate or minimise this MariaDB deadlock?
I'm struggling with a deadlock in my booking web application when there are many concurrent users.
Here are the relevant tables:
mariadb> explain bookings;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name            | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| surname               | varchar(20)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| address               | varchar(50)  | NO   |     |         |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mariadb> explain seats;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| booking_id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Create for seats table:
CREATE TABLE `seats` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `booking_id` (`booking_id`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`booking_id`) REFERENCES `bookings` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113007 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci

I have tried Googling this and also AI - one suggestion is adding indexes. As far as I can tell, this is already in place.
bookings.id has a unique index already, as it's a primary key.
seats.booking_id is a foreign key to bookings.id and as such has an index.
Another thing I read is "order your queries", well these are two INSERT statements that can occur concurrently under heavy load. I don't see how I can reorder anything.
Omitted for brevity, both "bookings" and "seats" tables also have foreign keys to other tables.
The INSERT query mentioned in the log is wrapped in a transaction. The transaction starts by inserting a new booking record, before moving on to inserting related seats. The transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ. MariaDB version is 10.5.22.
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2024-12-08 20:18:08 0x7fc9d1812700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 115387033, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 21614195, OS thread handle 140505494681344, query id 862030472 localhost dbutest Update
INSERT INTO `seats` (`id`,`booking_id`) VALUES (NULL, 2)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6821 page no 1012 n bits 776 index booking_id of table `testdb`.`seats` trx id 115387033 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 115387032, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
8 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 21614193, OS thread handle 140504780056320, query id 862030470 localhost dbutest Update
INSERT INTO `seats` (`id`,`booking_id`) VALUES (NULL, 1)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 6821 page no 1012 n bits 776 index booking_id of table `testdb`.`seats` trx id 115387032 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6821 page no 1012 n bits 776 index booking_id of table `testdb`.`seats` trx id 115387032 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)


Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE seats;.

By "wrapped in a transaction" do you mean the single query or other queries, too?

Why is id included in the INSERT?

Added create statement to my question. id is added in the insert query due to how the data is in the application model. In the case of a new insert, the id is 0 which causes a new auto increment id to be used. The transaction has an insert of the booking record, then a loop to insert seats for that record.

LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s) is suspicious. You might have a hung process. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462249/how-can-i-clear-a-transaction-deadlock

4 row lock(s) is also suspicious indicate there is something else holding locks.

A PRIMARY KEY is a KEY, so drop KEY id (id) USING BTREE,

Actually that was my error in reproducing the example for the question. That key is not present. I have updated my question.
